# Artificial Intelligence, how to start off good

Tags: artificial-intelligence

codingame and hackerearth (comp. programming sites out there) every 2-3 month organise a contest on AI programming in which we are given a 2D board game and our codes are run on there server and our bots play with others'.
Coming to the point, there are certain algorithms like minimax with alpha beta pruning, DFS, BFS, etc. which help you easily to get a decent rank. I see most of the top players talking about the same stuff.
The thing is where can I learn these algorithms and to become a good ai programmer what else should I need to know. I've heard about GAs (Genetic algorithms ) too like simulating some moves ahead in the game and decide on the basis of that what to do. But whenever I myself tried making such thing I failed. 
I mainly need a source to learn or some example programs which can help.
I'm sorry if my explanation was not correct, I am new in this community.
Thanks in advance. 
I am familiar with python and have good hands on c++ and JS.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to first learn the methods discussed there than going into GAs. GAs are easy to learn but would most probably not give good results.

Comment: My answer was unaccepted, but let me reiterate from my experience. Evolutionary computation (GAs) is an immature technology and a lot of researchers focus on this area because of ease of understanding. It is an area which as poor theoretical background and a lot of sub-par research output. It is hardly used in industry and only a handful of industrial applications exist. Not a wise choice to solve a problem as mentioned above. I would be happy to be proven wrong though!